# Mutation testing for other tests than unit tests?

Tags: testing, functional-programming, regression, end-to-end, mutation

I have been reading up on Mutation Testing: the idea of a set of code, changing values in your code and re-running tests to see if you have code mutations on your hand.

Now, I am responsible for a large number of Functional Automation Tests; Regression and End-to-end. The more I read up on mutation testing, the more I see that it's mainly used for Unit Tests and not really anything else.

Is it also possible to apply Mutation testing to functional regression and end-to-end tests? Or perhaps even to Gherkin scripts?

Comment: MT is more applicable to unit tests. For integration tests there exist other frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage mutation testing for integration-based tests.
Hence, the larger the test dependencies, the more opportunities for a test to fail.
Thus, when happy-path and sad-path test scenarios are added, adding mutation tests could be deemed redundant.

Mutation testing is an interesting approach for validating the quality of a unit test. However, I would also reccomend [Property-based testing](https://hypothesis.works/articles/what-is-property-based-testing/) as an alternative approach.